# Elementary Topology In Euclidean Spaces

Tags: real-analysis

Show that a set consisting of a finite number of points in E is bounded.

I am totally confused on how to prove this if someone can walk me through this, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is as confusing as "Given a finite number of students in the class show that money in a student's wallet is  limited".

Comment: Thanks for the example man I'll keep it in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say $E=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Then
$$\sup_{x\in E}||x||=\max\{||x_1||,\ldots,||x_n||\}<+\infty,$$
which by definition means that $E$ is bounded.